# Boxfuse run command does not find file in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloudcaptain

I have a Spring Boot application that has application.properties file in resource folder. That file also includes:
***server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certificate.jks***  . 
When running boxfuse on my local machine (boxfuse run myJar.jar) everything is ok (*Payload started in 01:02.631s -> https://127.0.0.1:8448*) but when I try to do ***boxfuse run -env=dev myJar:1.0*** the application fails to start due to *vb-1d056c6c => **java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/certificate.jks (No such file or directory**)* . I do not think this is a problem with my app, but with Boxfuse. What should I do?

Comment: Could it be that that image was fused with a previous version of your app? Could you try removing it and fusing a fresh one?

Comment: @Axel Yes that was the issue. Boxfuse saw that I already have an image with that version so it created a New version number. I was not paying atenttion at the beginning of the log. Maybe you can add the image version at the end of the log also? After or before the succes message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I already had an image with version 1.1 so Boxfuse created a new version number. I was not paying atenttion to the log so when I ran the deploy to AWS command, I was actually deploying the old version. Got to pay attention to logs